# How to send POST data without hidden element?

Tags: php

I wonder how to send a POST parameter without showing the my secret data in html source.

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="$secretdata">
```

`$secrerdata` must be sent as `$_POST["url"]` but I want to send it on server side.

Comment: What do you mean by "send on severe side" send from your server to some other server?

Comment: I guess it should be `value="<php print $secretdata; ?>"`

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible unless you never let the data reach the client. Otherwise the ""secret"" data will ALWAYS be visible to the user - either by intercepting the transmitted data or by looking at the HTML source or by looking at the JS source if you try to hide it using JS.

What you could do is storing the data in the `$_SESSION` array and access it via the same array on the second page instead of using POST. Of course you could assign it a field in `$_POST` manually if some (bad) code relies on it being in there.

Another option - which you should **only** use if you can't use the session for some reason - would be encrypting the data with a secret key that the user doesn't know (i.e. that is only used in server-side code).

Obviously you could also sent a POST request in your PHP code (using [curl](http://php.net/curl)) - but then the request doesn't originate from the user's IP and depending on what you want to do that might be a problem.

Comment: The thing is that it must be $_POST data and i can't control it  once it been sent. I don't want to show anything in the sourcecode.

Comment: If you cannot modify the code of the script the data is POSTed to you are simply out of luck since data the client sends it obviously visible to the client.

Comment: Isn't it possible to do something like this:
$_POST["name"] = "value";

Comment: Not true. You can intercept the submit with JS, then modify the values, then submit. That way, it will not be in the HTML quite so plainly.

Comment: Can i do it with PHP instead of JS?

Comment: @phant0m: "Or by looking at the JS source if you try to hide it using JS."

Comment: @OliwerIlliusGrevillius: See the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Ok, it might work! Do you have any code example?

Comment: Thats why I included the "quite so plainly"

Comment: @ThiefMaster is this correct? http://coderscult.com/php/php-curl/2008/05/20/how-to-post-data-with-curl-in-php/

Answer (score 2):

I think what you actually need is a session. There you can store data that will be handled only by the server and is associated with a specific user.

In order to use that, you need to put `session_start()` at the beginning of every page where this data needs to be available. Then you can use

```
$_SESSION['yourkey'] = 'Something';
```

to store data in this session. It's available afterwards as `$_SESSION['yourkey']` even on other pages.

You can find all information about session in the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).